# url returns JSON but with scrapy I got a weird response

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I struggle understanding the response I get from a simple address.
The address is [https://fr.getaround.com/search.json?address=Gare de Bordeaux Saint-Jean](https://fr.getaround.com/search.json?address=Gare%20de%20Bordeaux%20Saint-Jean) which give a long json response (>130k caracters).

The idea with this json is to then scrape the list of cars provided by the response.

getaround api is quite standard in its answers so even if there were no cars, I would still receive the global json structure with an empty cars list.

When trying with scrapy though I get a very short response : `b'{"redirect_to":"/"}'`

Here under is the code I am using

```
def start_requests(self):
    addresses= ["Gare de Bordeaux Saint-Jean"]       
    
    for address in addresses:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            f"https://fr.getaround.com/search.json?address={address}"
        )

def parse(self, response):
    print("--------------------------------------------------------\nRESPONSE\n--------------------------------------------------------")
    print(response)
    print("--------------------------------------------------------\nBODY\n--------------------------------------------------------")
    print(response.body)
```

I tried a few things :

- Using playwright

It basically wrap the previous response.body between some html tags

- Using the shell

Same response. I tried to force the method to GET (`request = request.replace(method="GET")`) or POST (`method="POST"`)

1. GET gives a 200 code with proper response in POSTMAN and 200 status with only a body being `b''` with scrapy shell
2. POST gives a 404 code in both POSTMAN and scrapy

- I tried enabling or not cookies with settings.py with no luck.
- I tried to scrape the main page (`fr.getaround.com`) out of which the response.body seems  fine.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

[Here](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20220812xxeDv7vG) the json response I get from POSTMAN / opening the url

Comment: I get the `{"redirect_to":"/"}` response when I click on the link.

Comment: Why do you think that's not JSON? It's in a byte string rather than a regular string; you can convert it with `.decode()`.

Comment: Interesting. I still have the proper json (over 130k characters)... PS : i edit my post, indeed that's json, jsut not what I want.

Comment: I also get that response with `curl`. How have you gotten the full response?

Comment: And if I do `requests.get('https://fr.getaround.com/search.json?address=Gare%20de%20Bordeaux%20Saint-Jean')`

Comment: I just added a link to the json I get with Postman or when opening the url. I'll try in a private tab to check if it's link to some cookie / session --> and yes it is... So nothing wrong with scrapy actualy. Now I feel dumb :D thanks for helping Barmar, I have some additional digging in their api to do

Comment: It's almost certain that you need to set *something* in the HTTP headers in order to get the desired result (the website is has detected that this is a scraping program). Typically this involves either setting a user agent (make the program identify itself as an actual web browser) and/or a referrer (claim that you got to this url from the search page, rather than a direct link). Or it can be a cookie/session issue, yes.

Comment: User Agent is automatically set by scrapy. Indeed it comes from my request. The actual request look like that `https://fr.getaround.com/search.json?address=Gare%20de%20Bordeaux%20Saint-Jean&car_sharing=true&city_display_name=&country_scope=FR&display_view=list&end_date=2022-08-31&end_time=10%3A00&latitude=44.8265&longitude=-0.5559&picked_car_ids=EMPTY&start_date=2022-08-29&start_time=10%3A00&user_interacted_with_car_sharing=false&view_mode=list` and I cut it a lot. It gave me an answer due to existing cookie or opened session and made me believe I removed only unnecessary things.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Web browser gets the redirecet response, not the full JSON.

Comment: So actually they only need the latitude and longitude. Something like this works in scrapy : https://fr.getaround.com/search.json?latitude=44.8265&longitude=-0.5559. 
While I understand why I got an answer from Chrome (badly formated url gives the last valid url answer in getaround) I still don't understand how POSTMAN got me an answer based on a session opened in Chrome... and still maange to navigate in pages with `&page=x`
Anyway that's a great news, easier to work with lat/long than an address

Comment: `User Agent is automatically set by scrapy` . This is not a  completely correct. Actually, scrapy has several ways to inject it. If  you get 403 or  such type of errors then to add the real user agent is a must

Comment: @F.Hoque. I may be wrong but I think scrapy uses a default user agent (something like Scrapy<version>). But in my case, the proper answer should have been that scrapy automaticaly sets the user agent as I am using scrapy_user_agents middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the difference between the request opened in Chrome / Postman and what scrapy was doing is a simple matter of cookie.
In my case POSTMAN add some saved cookies (maybe from an initial query) which allowed getaround to still provide an answer to a badly formated url based on the request out of which the cookies were generated

So the issue is not from scrapy but from non discarded cookies within Postman (the little "Cookies" link just under the Send button) that made me believe my GET requests were correct.